# Лосиный/лосинный

Tags: орфография

Правильно я думаю, что надо писать *лосиная шкура, лосиный мех, лосиная голова, лосиный рог, лосиное мясо* (от слова *лось*), но *лосинный стейк, лосинная котлета, лосинная колбаска* (от слова *лосина*)?